# DefaultList columns header is half hidden in fluentui

Tags: css, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I am using fluentui for creating the webapp. I used DefaultList component to show the list of data.

But the header of all the columns is half hidden like below
[image]

All the rows below are being visible correctly.

This is the code snippet I am using

```
<DetailsList
        items={operations}
        columns={columns}
    checkboxVisibility={2}
    setKey="set"
    selectionMode={SelectionMode.none}
    onRenderItemColumn={_renderItemColumn}
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fixed somehow. I think it is the browser's issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).